# How can I show some endpoints only admin

Tags: node.js, api-doc, api-documentation

I created an apidoc when I published that everyone can see all endpoints. Is there a way to add restriction? I want to create an admin and user role. The admin can see all endpoints but user can see some endpoints on document. How can I do?

Comment: If admins log on to your application (their credentials prove they are really admins), while everyone else need not logon, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979943/how-to-call-a-middleware-function-from-inside-a-middleware-function might help you.

Comment: I mentioned https://apidocjs.com/ that is different authentication. Apidoc is just publishing folder.